# Quickly look-up usages, options and attributes of symbols

Tags: dynamic, options, palettes, attributes

When I'm writing code in the front-end, I find myself very often looking up the list of options of a symbol over and over again in the documentation center. In most cases you find there a list of available options, but sometimes not and you may end up typing `Options[Get]` in your current notebook.

Even worse is the situation with `Attributes` which are extremely helpful especial when you do something with non-standard evaluation. In this case, I often just want to know *Does a function hold its arguments?* or *Is this function listable?* to give two examples.

**Question:** Isn't there a one-click palette solution for this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For this purpose, I wrote a small *Symbol Information Palette*. This palette let's you quickly look up usages, options and attributes of symbols and was tested on *Mac OSX* and *Linux*.

[image]

### Installation

The source code is hosted [on my GitHub site](https://github.com/halirutan/SymbolInformationPalette) but to *preview* or *install* the palette you only have to evaluate this:

```
Get["http://goo.gl/QPywk"]
```

The link is just shortened and points only to the [raw sources](https://raw.github.com/halirutan/SymbolInformationPalette/master/SymbolInformationPalette.m) of my palette on GitHub.

After evaluation you get 3 buttons. *Show Palette* let's you test it without installing something. *Install Palette* installs the palette in the user palette directory

```
FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "Palettes"}]
```

With *Install Path* you can install it in a different location.

### Usage

It is designed to be as minimal and informative as possible. The windows created by this palette have no <kbd>Close</kbd> or <kbd>OK</kbd> button, instead (since they are dialogs) they are closed by simply hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

If you want information about a symbol, you can, but you don't need to select it and press a button. It is sufficient when the cursor is anywhere *in* or *at* the symbol. This means to get information about `Graphics` the cursor just needs to be at any of the `|` when you click a button: `|G|r|a|p|h|i|c|s|`.

**Usage button:** The *Usage* button displays the usage message of a symbol. You can use the **second mouse button** and click on the this window and the documentation center opens automatically the page of the symbol. Here an example for `Get`

[image]

Please note, that if you select something which has no usage message and you see the window with *No usage message available* you can still click on it to search the documentation center.

**Options button**

The options button displays a custom made panel which is awesome. You get a scroll-able list of all options of a symbol and you can click on each option to get an *inline view* of the usage of this option. Additionally, when being over a such an inline usage message for a second you get a tooltip with the default value. Not to mention, that you can use always the secondary click to open the documentation of this option!

[image]

**Attributes button:** Ever wondered why your `Plot` uses only one color when you don't give an explicit `List` of functions? Ever wondered why something is evaluated or not evaluated as you expect it. This button is a quick way to display all `Attributes` of symbol neatly arranged.

[image]

### Further development

If I find time, then I want to implement some further features

- Changing of attributes if possible.
- Investigate in `OwnValue`, `UpValues`, `DownValues`, `SubValues`, `FormatValues`, `NValues`
- Creation of template code to insert custom code snips into built-in function

### Known Issues

jVincent mentioned that the option-panel is sometimes slow. In this panel, every button is a small `DynamicModule` because I couldn't find a way to implement the behaviour I wanted with the usual tools like `Button`. As example, jVincent mentioned the option-panel of `CreatePalette` which is probably a bad choice for generalisation because with its 281 options it plays in the top 10 of the 4623 symbols in `Names["*"]` regarding number of options. Even `Graphics` has only 38 options.

Comment: Normally, I'd object to someone calling their own work "awesome," however, I think it qualifies. +1

Comment: @rcollyer This *awesome* is an awesome which expresses how long it took me fiddling around with `Button`, `Toggler`, `Opener` and friend before finally throwing everything away and building my own `Mouseover`, `EventHandler` solution which works quite reasonable, even for a long list of options.

Comment: Cool. I'll have to look through the code when it isn't approaching 3 in the morning.

Comment: Before I even try: is this going to work in version 7?  Boy I sure hope so.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I haven't tried it but if nothing really bad happens, we should get it going.

Comment: The options panel seems very sluggish at times. If you are generating all usage cells when opening, perhaps it would help to delay the generation until it's opened the first time. A good symbol to see this on is CreatePalette

Comment: @jVincent Please see my explanation at the end.

Comment: Very nice. Thanks you. When I pressed on Usage using my all time favourite 'Plot' function I triggered an internal error in V9.0. But only the first time. Just some funny glitch I suppose.

Comment: @Matariki Can you specify exactly what operating system you have and can you post the error message you are seeing?

Comment: I am using Mac OS 10.8.2 But I can't recreate the error. I don't recall the wording. I assume it was just the state my Mathematica session was in. I had used it for days and can't recreate every step I did. I don't think this is anything you need to worry about particularly if no one else encounters it. Thanks again for a great tool.

Comment: @halirutan when I try to load your palette with Get["http://goo.gl/QPywk"] or with Get["https://raw.github.com/halirutan/SymbolInformationPalette/master/SymbolInformationPalette.m"] I get a Get::noopen message. I am using version 8.01 in Windows. Are the links dead?