# Simple Choice-Dialog like the auto-completion popup

Tags: front-end, gui-construction, keyboard, dialog-window

What I want is pretty simple, nevertheless, after half an hour I have only unsatisfying solutions here. Let me ask you who might work more often with *Mathematica*'s GUI elements:

Is there a way to implement a dialog in *Mathematica* which works in general like the autocompletion popup.

> [image]

The dialog doesn't have to popup automatically but it should have the following features:

- it is a **fixed** list of entries, where the first entry is always selected and you can use the arrow keys to navigate up and down
- on <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> the dialog closes where in the first case, some identifier with the selected entry is returned
- I can use a unique "short-key" which lets me directly select and return one of the entries. So for instance if my list of choices is `{"Module","Block","With"}` I could use e.g. `m`, `b` and `w` to select the corresponding entry.

I have played with various dialogs, button bars and `EventHandler` without luck. Bevor I investigate further, I thought asking is probably the better choice.

Comment: I once created a nice solution for this problem for one of my customers.  I know that it was a rather lenghty function which took me hours of work.  Thus, I think you are not underestimating the complexity of the problem.

Comment: @ArielSepulveda I do have a hand-crafted list-dialog-clickedy-clack too for my [symbol information palette](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16816/187) but this lacks of the short-cuts and arrow keys. You always have to click. Additionally, and I haven't mentioned this here, I would like the dialog to popup at cursor (not mouse!) position. This seems impossible to achieve as far as I can tell. As always, if you want to do a real application with the dynamic UI elements it is *never* a one-line like advertised in the million toy-demonstrations.

Comment: I'm not sure of what you mean by popup at cursor but maybe something can be done by means of InputField.  You can move from one InputField to the next by using Tab, once you get to the desired field, typing the search string may be enough to dynamically popup the matches as a list and then use the arrow keys to navigate to the desired one, and finally, conclude the selection with a "ReturnKeyDown" which will be "collected" by the EventHandler.  Thus, you may have to end up combining Dynamic with Button and EventHandler.  Complicated? Yes, but maybe not impossible ;)

Comment: @ArielSepulveda With *popup at cursor* I mean the behavior the autocompletion popup shows: It appears exactly beneath your current cursor position where you type.

Comment: @halirutan At last WC, WRI devs (don't remember who exactly) said that those floating gui elements are going to be introduced. No specific date/time was mentioned so I'd not wait for it though.

Comment: Is "popup at cursor" requirement a must for an answer?

Comment: @Kuba I tried to re-implement auto-completion for the FE. So the goal is that when you start typing, a pop-up appears with suggestions, just like it does with the normal auto-completion. This is why the *at cursor position* would be very helpful and why the pop-up should grab some of the keyboards attention.

Comment: You can mimic floating element with Notebook that has `WindowFrame->"Frameless"` + few other options. You also would have to store InputNotebook reference while invoking it so you can set proper `SelectedNotebook` after you clikc Esc or Enter. And those key events can be attached to this notebook with `NotebookEventActions`, as well as arrows' events. So the only thing that is missing is the `WindowsMargins` option to set possition of the notebook. Don't know how to get the cursor position.

Comment: One could also write an empty module and use [FrontEnd`AttachedCell](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99322/5478). But I find it ugly (writing module). I'm going to ask a question, which when answered will solve this issue.

Answer (score 7):

#### Edit

Once again [b3m2a1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56135/simple-choice-dialog-like-the-auto-completion-popup/164680?noredirect=1#comment435935_164680) provided more detailed information about a FE's feature so I have to retract my claim that it is not worth an effort to create a popup on cursor position as opposed to e.g. in the corner of the notebook.

#### Main

The following answer is closely related to [Live code templates](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/164653/5478) I'm working on in a free time.

I will outline two alternative methods, attached cell vs frameless palette. (the linked topic uses the former one but without attaching on a cursor position)

#### tl;dr;

Make sure you saved your work, this is a rough implementation and the "Cell" approach uses an undocumented `AttachedCell`.

- Run code from the last section,
- run `testPopup["Palette"]`
- hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to interact with menu.

This one is not on cursor position because it is tough :) this one is:

- `testPopup["Cell"]`

[image]

#### Cell vs. Palette

- Palette is not clipped by a parent notebook what is very convenient when the cursor is close to the bottom/right edge or the menu is not small.
- Palette notebook is documented
- `AttachedCell` can be placed directly on a cursor position, thanks to an `UndocumentedGetSelectionPacket`. It is not easy with Palette because `Undocu...` does not account on `DockedCells` and additionaly we need to do `WindowMargins` arithmetic.

#### Cursor position

```
FrontEndExecute @ FrontEnd`UndocumentedGetSelectionPacket @ InputNotebook[]
```

[image]

its `"VirtualSelectionRectangle"` value is a cursor position with respect to the bottom left edge of the very bottom docked cell (or a nb menu).

#### Key events

Whatever wrapper you use the key point is to create a `DynamicModule` that will temporarily overwrite parent notebook's `NotebookEventActions` on `Initialization` and will revert old settings on `Deinitialization` (you thought you will never use this opition, didn't you?).

Once Arrows/Enter/Esc are overwritten there is no problem in "KeyDown" event and check if an event key isn't a member of defined shortcuts.

#### Demo code

`CenterToParent` is taken from [How to center a dialog with respect to a parent notebook](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/146308/5478)

```
testPopup[type:"Cell"|"Palette":"Cell"]:=CreateDocument[{}
, WindowTitle -> type <> " popup menu"
, StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[{
    Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]]
  , Cell[StyleData["Notebook"]
    , NotebookEventActions -> {{"MenuCommand", "InsertNewGraphic"}:>openPopup[type]} (*Ctrl+1*)
    ]    
  }]
];

items = { 
<|"lbl"->"item 1","action":>NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], "item1"],"shortkey" -> "m"|>, 
<|"lbl"->"item 2","action":>NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], "item2"],"shortkey" -> "k"|>,
<|"lbl"->"item 2","action":>NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], "item3"],"shortkey" -> "l"|>
};


openPopup["Palette"]:= NotebookPut @ CenterToParent @ Notebook[
  List @ Cell[BoxData @ ToBoxes @ popupMenu["Palette"]
  , CellFrameMargins->{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
  , CellMargins->{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}    
  ]        
, StyleDefinitions->"Dialog.nb"
, WindowClickSelect->False
, WindowFloating->True
, WindowFrame->"Frameless"
, WindowSize->All
, Background->LightBlue
, WindowElements->{}
, WindowFrameElements->{}    
];

openPopup["Cell"] := Module[{sel,fromTop, fromLeft}
, Catch[
    sel = FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`UndocumentedGetSelectionPacket@ 
      InputNotebook[]
  ; If[ 
      MatchQ[sel, KeyValuePattern[{"CellSelectionType" -> "ContentSelection", "SelectionType" -> "CursorRight"}]]
    , {fromLeft,fromTop} = Lookup[sel, "VirtualSelectionRectangle", {{0,0},{0,0}}][[All, 1]]
    , Beep[];Throw@$Canceled
    ]
  ; MathLink`CallFrontEnd[
      FrontEnd`AttachCell[
        EvaluationNotebook[]
      , Cell @ BoxData @ ToBoxes @ popupMenu["Cell"]
      , {Offset[{-fromLeft,-fromTop},0], {Left,Top}}
      , {Left,Top}
      , "ClosingActions"->{ "OutsideMouseClick" }
      ]  
    ]
  ]  
];

popupMenu[type_]:=DynamicModule[
  {item=1,thisObject, parentObject, menuClose, items = items, itemsLength = Length@items}
, Table[With[{i=i},
   EventHandler[#, "MouseEntered":>(item = i)]& @ Button[
     Style[
     StringTemplate["`lbl` (`shortkey`)"]@items[[i]], Bold, FontColor-> Dynamic@If[item==i,Darker@Red,Darker@Green]]
   , items[[i,"action"]]; menuClose[]
  , FrameMargins->15
   , ImageMargins->0
   , Appearance->FrontEndResource["FEExpressions","GrayNinePatchAppearance"]
   ]]
  , {i, itemsLength}
 ]//Column[#,Spacings->0]&
 , Initialization:>(
   If[
     type === "Palette"
   ,
     thisObject = EvaluationNotebook[];
     menuClose[]:=NotebookClose @ thisObject
   , 
     thisObject = EvaluationCell[];
     menuClose[]:=NotebookDelete @ thisObject
   ];
   parentObject = InputNotebook[];


   CurrentValue[parentObject, NotebookEventActions] = {
     "UpArrowKeyDown":>(item=Mod[item-1,itemsLength,1])
   , "DownArrowKeyDown":>(item=Mod[item+1,itemsLength,1])
   , "EscapeKeyDown":>menuClose[]
   , "ReturnKeyDown" :> (items[[item, 2]]; menuClose[])
   , "KeyDown" :> If[
       MemberQ[items[[;;, "shortkey"]], CurrentValue["EventKey"]]
     , (#action& /@ Select[items, #shortkey === CurrentValue["EventKey"]&]);menuClose[]
     ]
   , "MouseClicked" :>  menuClose[] 
  }
)
 , Deinitialization:>(
  CurrentValue[parentObject,NotebookEventActions]=Inherited
)
]


CenterToParent::usage =  "CenterToParent[DialogInput[...]] etc, will make the dialog centered with respect to the parent notebook";

CenterToParent // Attributes = {HoldFirst};

CenterToParent[ dialog_[whatever__, opts : OptionsPattern[]]  ] := With[
    {apc = AbsoluteCurrentValue}
  , With[
        { parentCenter = Transpose @ {
              apc[WindowMargins][[;; , 1]] + .5 apc[ WindowSize]
            , {Automatic, Automatic}
          }
        }
      , dialog[
            whatever
          , NotebookDynamicExpression :> Refresh[
                SetOptions[
                    EvaluationNotebook[]
                  , WindowMargins -> (parentCenter - Transpose[{.5 apc[WindowSize], {0, 0}}])
                  , NotebookDynamicExpression -> None
                ]
              , None
            ]
          , opts 
        ]
     ]
  ];
```

Comment: I forgot to update that answer, but `AttachedCell` can actually take an `Offset` spec, so it can be in arbitrary directions. I'll get to that later today. In the meantime you can see my implementation of a top-level attacher [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools/blob/9f817b58033db5ef00ee15f3ee382264ed86e7d4/Packages/FETools.m#L1473) which will hopefully make it clearer how this works.

Comment: Thanks, I will update the answer. I was playing with Offset but after couple of FE crashes and forgetting about coordinates orientation I wrongly assumed it does not work. Thanks again.