# How can I create my own hover message?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, cells, customization

I wanted to know how this "Saving to the Wolfram Cloud" message works?

[image]

It's useful because it hovers above the notebook's content even when scrolling and I'd like to change the text and reuse it for my own purposes.

Comment: [`DockedCells`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DockedCells.html)? [`StatusArea`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StatusArea.html)? [`WindowStatusarea`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WindowStatusArea.html)? Those all came to mind when you described this, but I don't think any of them achieve it _immediately_. But they may help :)

Comment: @Kuba only for a second while saving the notebook to the cloud

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is almost certainly an `AttachedCell`, an undocumented feature which proves to be very useful.

```
MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`AttachCell[
  EvaluationNotebook[],
  Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@Panel@DateString[]],
  Bottom, Bottom,
  "ClosingActions" -> {"OutsideMouseClick"}]
]
```

[image]

This will attatch a cell at the bottom of the notebook. You can leave `ClosingActions` empty if you want it to stay there. Or change it but **do not put there "ParentChanged"** item. This will crash the front end.

More info about syntax:

- [What is FrontEnd`AttachedCell?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/99292/5478)
- [FrontEndPackets / AttachCell - DetachCell](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133523/5478)