# Get an Attached Cell

Tags: front-end, undocumented

I want to dig into what this cell is doing:

[image: i button cell]

It's clearly an [attached cell](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99292/what-is-frontendattachedcell) but I can't get at it. Here's what I've tried:

[`Cells`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cells.html) (pretty obviously not gonna work, but worth the try

```
Dynamic[
 cellsAll =
  Nest[
   Cases[
     Union[#,
      Flatten@Map[FrontEndExecute@*FrontEnd`ObjectChildren, #]
      ],
     _CellObject
     ] &,
   FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`ObjectChildren[$FrontEnd],
   15
   ];
 Select[cellsAll,
   ParentNotebook[#] =!= $Failed &&

     FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`AttachedCellParent[#] =!= $Failed &
   ] // Length,
 UpdateInterval -> 5,
 TrackedSymbols :> {}
 ]
```

Obviously I waited for a round of the i button to pop up. Still nothing.

So... is there any way to get at these? (if you didn't get it when it was created)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That drop down menu is not an AttachedCell.

Comment: Fascinating. What is it then? Is it accessible within Mathematica?

Comment: It is a custom control, built in native code.  I am not aware of any top level entry point for it.

Comment: Good to know, thanks.

Comment: Still haven't been able to figure out how one gets an attached cell without having captured it at creation time. Any hints there?

Comment: I do not believe that is possible.  Is there a particular problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Nope. Pure curiosity.