# Obtaining the correct size of notebooks

Tags: front-end, notebooks

I have a notebook, `nb`, on which I want to layer another notebook, `di`, which has [`WindowFrame`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WindowFrame.html) set to `"Frameless"`.

Here's my naive layering attempt just using the same [`WindowMargins`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WindowMargins.html) and [`WindowFrame`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WindowFrame.html):

```
nb = CreateDocument[];
di =
 CreateDocument["",
  WindowSize -> AbsoluteCurrentValue[nb, WindowSize],
  WindowMargins -> AbsoluteCurrentValue[nb, WindowMargins],
  WindowElements -> None,
  WindowFrameElements -> None,
  WindowFrame -> "Frameless",
  WindowOpacity -> .5,
  Background -> Blue
  ]
```

But we can see it's slightly off:

[image: slight issue]

So how do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Since the frame is `"Frameless"` the trick is to compute the true `WindowSize` from the `WindowMargins`:

```
trueWindowSize[
   marg : {{_, _}, {_, _}},
   rec : {{_, _}, {_, _}} | Automatic : Automatic
   ] :=
  With[
   {
    sr =
     Replace[rec,
      Automatic :>
       Lookup[
        AbsoluteOptions[$FrontEnd, ScreenRectangle],
        ScreenRectangle
        ]
      ]
    },
   {
    (sr[[1, 2]] - marg[[1, 2]]) -
     (sr[[1, 1]] + marg[[1, 1]]),
    sr[[2, 2]] - marg[[2, 2]] -
     (sr[[2, 1]] + marg[[2, 1]])
    }
   ];
trueWindowSize[
  nb_NotebookObject,
  rec : {{_, _}, {_, _}} | Automatic : Automatic
  ] :=
 trueWindowSize[AbsoluteCurrentValue[nb, WindowMargins], rec]
```

Then:

```
nb = CreateDocument[];
di =
 CreateDocument["",
  WindowSize -> trueWindowSize[nb],
  WindowMargins -> AbsoluteCurrentValue[nb, WindowMargins],
  WindowElements -> None,
  WindowFrameElements -> None,
  WindowFrame -> "Frameless",
  WindowOpacity -> .5,
  Background -> Blue
  ]
```

[image: fixed]

#### Extended Answer:

But there are subtleties here to explore.

To illustrate this, let's compute the `WindowSize` and `WindowMargins` for a pile of different window configurations:

```
windowSize[frame_, elems_, frelems_, close : True | False : True] :=
 
 With[{
   sr =
    Lookup[
     AbsoluteOptions[$FrontEnd, ScreenRectangle],
     ScreenRectangle
     ],
   nb =
    CreateDocument[
     Panel["", Background -> Yellow, ImageSize -> {500, 500}],
     WindowSize -> All,
     WindowFrame -> frame,
     WindowElements -> elems,
     WindowFrameElements -> frelems,
     Visible -> False
     ]},
  If[close,
     NotebookClose[nb];
     <|
      "GivenSize" -> #[WindowSize],
      "TrueSize" -> trueWindowSize[#[WindowMargins], sr]
      |>,
     {nb,
      <|
       "GivenSize" -> #[WindowSize],
       "TrueSize" -> trueWindowSize[#[WindowMargins], sr]
       |>
      }
     ] &@
   Association@
    AbsoluteOptions[nb, {WindowSize, WindowMargins}]
  ]
windowSize[a : {_, _, _}, 
  b : {_, _, _}] :=
 (NotebookClose@*First /@ #; 
    Subtract[#[[1, 2]], #[[2, 2]]]) &@
  {
   windowSize @@ Append[a, False],
   windowSize @@ Append[b, False]
   }

windowSizeData =
  AssociationMap[
   windowSize[#Frame, #Elements, #FrameElements] &,
   AssociationThread[
      {"Frame", "Elements", "FrameElements"},
      #
      ] & /@
    Tuples[
     {
      {"Frameless", "Generic", "ModalDialog", "ModelessDialog", 
       "MovableModalDialog", "Normal", "Palette", "ThinFrame"},
      Subsets[
       {"HorizontalScrollBar", "MagnificationPopUp", "StatusArea", 
        "VerticalScrollBar"}, 1
       ],
      Subsets[
       {"CloseBox", "ZoomBox", "ResizeArea"},
       1
       ]
      }
     ]
   ];
```

Then we'll group this by discrepancy between stated and real window size:

```
GroupBy[Normal[windowSizeData],
   (Last[#]["TrueSize"] - Last[#]["GivenSize"] &) -> First] // 
  KeySort // Map[Take[#, 5] &] // Dataset
```

[image: sample]

And we see the `WindowSize` discrepancy just comes out of the frame. So when we align notebooks we need to account for that. On the other hand, sometimes we may also want to account for in-frame elements, so here's a comparative way to compute size differences based on frame and elements:

```
windowSizeAdjustments[
   baseStyle :
    {_, _, _} :
    {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic
     },
   newStyle :
    {_, _, _} :
    {"Frameless", None, None}
   ] :=
  windowSizeAdjustments[baseStyle, newStyle] =
   Module[{
     nb =
      CreateDocument[
       Panel["",
        Background -> Yellow,
        ImageSize -> {500, 500}],
       Visible -> False,
       WindowSize -> All,
       WindowFrame -> baseStyle[[1]],
       WindowElements -> baseStyle[[2]],
       WindowFrameElements -> baseStyle[[3]]
       ],
     base,
     frame,
     elem
     },
    base = trueWindowSize[nb];
    SetOptions[nb,
     {
      WindowFrame -> newStyle[[1]],
      WindowFrameElements -> None,
      WindowElements -> None
      }];
    frame =
     trueWindowSize[nb];
    SetOptions[nb,
     {
      WindowFrame -> baseStyle[[1]],
      WindowFrameElements -> newStyle[[2]],
      WindowElements -> newStyle[[3]]
      }];
    elem =
     trueWindowSize[nb];
    NotebookClose[nb];
    <|
     "Elements" -> base - elem,
     "Frame" -> base - frame
     |>
    ];
windowSizeAdjustments[
   nb1 : _Notebook | Automatic : Automatic,
   dialog_Notebook
   ] :=
  Module[{
    opsBase =
     Switch[nb1,
      Automatic,
      {
       WindowFrame -> Automatic,
       WindowElements -> Automatic,
       WindowFrameElements -> Automatic
       },
      _Notebook,
      Association@Join[Options[Notebook], List @@ Rest[nb1]]
      ],
    ops = Association@Join[Options[Notebook], List @@ Rest[dialog]]
    },
   windowSizeAdjustments[
    {
     Lookup[opsBase, WindowFrame, Automatic],
     Lookup[opsBase, WindowFrameElements, Automatic],
     Lookup[opsBase, WindowElements, Automatic]
     },
    {
     Lookup[ops, WindowFrame, "Frameless"],
     Lookup[ops, WindowFrameElements, None],
     Lookup[ops, WindowElements, None]
     }
    ]
   ];
```

And then we can use this to compute the discrepancy for different notebooks:

```
nb = Notebook[{}];
di =
  Notebook[{},
   WindowElements -> None,
   WindowFrameElements -> None,
   WindowFrame -> "ThinFrame",
   WindowOpacity -> .5,
   Background -> Blue,
   System`CellInsertionPointCell -> None,
   System`CellInsertionPointColor -> Blue,
   System`BlinkingCellInsertionPoint -> False
   ];
windowSizeAdjustments[nb, di]

<|"Elements" -> {0, 0}, "Frame" -> {-2, 20}|>
```

And we can make use of this for any frame style (note, beware of the modal frame styles -- you'll have to quit Mathematica to get rid of them, although usually you can say Cancel at the "Save changes to ..." dialog):

```
NotebookClose /@ {nbObj, diObj};
nbObj = CreateDocument[nb, WindowSize -> {250, 250}];
diObj =
 Block[{frameStyle = "ThinFrame"},
  CreateDocument[di,
   WindowSize ->
    AbsoluteCurrentValue[nbObj, WindowSize] +
     windowSizeAdjustments[nb, Insert[di, WindowFrame -> frameStyle]][
      "Frame"],
   WindowMargins -> AbsoluteCurrentValue[nbObj, WindowMargins],
   WindowFrame -> frameStyle
   ]
  ]
```

[image: thin frame]

```
NotebookClose /@ {nbObj, diObj};
nbObj = CreateDocument[nb, WindowSize -> {250, 250}];
diObj =
 Block[{frameStyle = "ModelessDialog"},
  CreateDocument[di,
   WindowSize ->
    AbsoluteCurrentValue[nbObj, WindowSize] +
     windowSizeAdjustments[nb, Insert[di, WindowFrame -> frameStyle]][
      "Frame"],
   WindowMargins -> AbsoluteCurrentValue[nbObj, WindowMargins],
   WindowFrame -> frameStyle
   ]
  ]
```

[image: modeless dialog]